# Porting android code into objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, porting

I have an android game thats basically completed and I want to start porting it to iOS.

I'm completely foreign to objective c and I have no idea where to start. In android I have a surface view, canvas, and a game loop which draws and posts the canvas. What's the iOS equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

First, be very careful of trying to transliterate between languages. You can't just pick up Java idioms and "do the same thing" on iOS in many cases. Many things are done with a completely different approach (threading is a major example; drawing is often done differently as well). You should spend some time learning the platform first or you'll get something that "almost" works and chase bugs and performance problems forever.

That said, the tool you probably want to study is [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org) which is a very good 3rdparty toolkit for building 2D games on iPhone. This is generally a much better approach than trying to build it up from scratch and should have a lower learning curve for game dev.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know how you should port without knowing the nature of your game but most iOS games are written in OpenGL which is very extendable.  It has some optimization tricks that can play a big role in how you architect your rendering pipeline though.

If you decide to go with OpenGL you should check out this Stanford talk presented by NGMoco on how to do this...
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNr5I3ZRecE

Comment: it's a simple 2D game. the graphics will just consist of drawing images to screen. all i need to kno is how the graphics work and how the view controller works, if its anything similar to android.

Comment: You can even use OpenGL for 2D and 2.5D games but if it's really really simple then you can use UIImage instances and a single subclass of NSViewController for setting up the view and driving the logic.  Animating the positions and other rendering elements of images is dead simple with UIView's animation methods as well.

Comment: Does this include image scaling, skewing, and rotations? Oh there's actually one component in my game that requires rendering a radial gradient that's of custom height and length and then rotating it.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.  Gradient rendering code is a bit more complex but it can be done.

Comment: Oh one more thing. There will be many images on screen and the game runs at 30fps. Would it be faster to go OpenGL or use UIImage?